# Excel spread sheet not sorting correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created an  Excel spreadsheet for data purposes only. No formulas. Many columns and rows of entries.

One of the columns is titled name is `music` and the next column is a `number` that has been assigned to that piece of music.

I primarily use a numerical sort. But the director uses an alpha sort.

Everything was fine until I inserted a few rows to add additional entries.

Now when I sort, some of the rows create a duplicate  and assign the next consecutive number even though that number is already assigned to another piece of music. If I go back to the numerical sort it's fine.

In the Alpha sort both pieces of music assigned to that number appear. If I delete the duplicate it's fine but  as soon as I saw it again it duplicated again.

Comment: "...some of the rows create a duplicate and assign the next consecutive number..."  What do you mean by assign? Can you re-confirm there are no formulas in your sheet?

Comment: Why you inserted new rows? Isn't sufficient to append new data just bellow the last filled row?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or make an example of your Data to reproduce what is happening

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Look at inserting a table in Excel to put all your data in the worksheet in a format with all column header filters, etc. and it doesn't get out of whack...

Comment: Whenever I read that someone is using Excel "for data purposes only", I shiver. While it's simple to use Excel is **NOT** a database. Please, if you need a database, use a database. Even something like Access is better than Excel as database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert your range to a **table** because the range's sort may have other dependencies, e. g. from the actual selection.

Select an arbitrary cell in your range (click on it), then click on the `Insert` tab and in then click the `Table` icon.

Tables has many other advantages for the data manipulation - comfortable sorting, filtering, summarizing are some of them.